# How do I unlock and recruit Asagi in Disgaea 2: Dark Hero Days?

Tags: disgaea-2

I've been skimming walkthoughs finding out the exact requirements needed to unlock and recruit Asagi for Disgaea 2: Dark Hero Days. Originally I thought I just needed to rack up 33 felonies but then I [read here](http://www.gamesradar.com/cheats/12529/) that another requirement is Subsequent cycle.  It is also the first time it says the bill unlocks Extra Stage 1.

So what are the exact requirements (felonies, bills, maps to be cleared, etc.) that I need to unlock and recruit Asagi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being in NG+

33felonies

A law will appear, pass it, do the map, you ll get Asagi in monster form.

Once Asagi lvl1000 you ll have another law to make her human.